# Rails has_many belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and basically, as others, have the same question in my mind. I want to link two tables to each other. But I couldn't do it. Help me o'mighty stackoverflow users.

Users class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :password, :username, :oauth_token, :provider, :uid, :oauth_expires_at, :picture, :email, :name, :location, :gender, :updated_at, :is_admin
  has_many :posts   
end
```

Posts class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :details, :title, :user_id, :picture
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In terminal, I log into rails console and say:

```
@allusers = Users.all
@allposts = Users.Posts.all
```

And it gives and error, are there any other method or Ruby code to link these tables?

Comment: Have you created a link table between the two in your database?

Comment: If it is a 1:n association, there is no extra table necessary. the foreign_key is on the posts table => see Post model attr_accessible :user_id => so the tables should be okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want as a result:

```
@allusers = User.all # returns all users of the users table
@allposts = Post.all # returns all posts of the posts table
@user = User.first # returns first user of the users table
@posts = @user.posts # returns all posts of the first user of the posts table
@posts = User.first.posts # also returns all posts of the first user of the posts table
```

You can read out more about querying here:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3
- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

**UPDATE**

```
@posts = User.where(:id => 123).first.posts # returns all posts of the user with the id 123. => all posts of the posts table which have the user_id 123 will be returned.
```

if you have a current_user method => returns current logged in user, you can simple fetch his posts with:

```
@posts = current_user.posts
```

Comment: But if I do User.first.posts and get the post, how can I get the information regarding which user wrote that post? There is a user_id attribute in Posts btw

Comment: I updated my answer. For more information simple check out the links to get an idea how active record is working..

Comment: Thank you, but you misunderstood. Let's say I used User.all.posts(don't know if the syntax is correct) in controller and show the news and the according writer's detail in a "Show All Posts" page. How can I do that?

Comment: But that was not your question from above :). You should add a new question. If you have a page with "Show all posts" you can simple fetch the posts of the current_user and save them in an instance variable. On your "Show all posts" page you can show the writer´s detail simple with for example: Name: current_user.name..and so on.. the posts could be rendered through a your_instance_variable.each..

Answer (score 3):

```
@allposts = Users.Posts.all
```

This needs to be

```
@allposts= Post.all
```

If you want the posts of a specific user, create one user, then do:

```
User.first.posts
```

If you want to get all posts and the user information that belongs to them without doing extra queries, try:

```
@allposts= Post.include(:user).all
```

This way `@allposts.first.user` will not cause an extra query.

Answer (score 1):

```
@allusers = User.all
```

**To Collect all posts**

```
@allposts = []

@allusers.each do |user|
 @posts = user.posts
    @posts.each do |post|
      @allposts << post
    end
end
```

**To collect a specific user's posts (here showing for first user)**

```
@allposts = User.first.posts
```

Comment: that´ts to complicated, and in your example allposts and allpost instance variable is not the same. your first allposts is simple Post.all, and your second allposts is correct, but returns only the posts from the first user, and not all posts in the posts table.

Comment: isn't that approach too resource consuming? are there any more efficient method in rails? or is it the only approach